# DML currently not allowed - trying to log exception in a custom object inside the constructor

Tags: visualforce, error, debugging, logging

I have a controller extension that makes a get request inside the constructor to get some information from an api.

```
public extension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    Account accountRecord = (Account) stdController.getRecord();
    accountInfo = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountRecord.Id];

    // Required to render the infomation when user click on the button
    getInfosFromApi(accountInfo.Name);
}

private HttpResponse getInfoFromApi(String name) {
    try {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setEndpoint(getUri(name));
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        // Use this response to render some information on the VF page
        return response;
    } catch (Exception error) {
        // Just get the error message and save it in the custom object.
        SaveException.log(error); // Here the error occurs, because I can't use a dml operation inside the constructor directly or indirectly.
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I click to access the page to test if the error is being saved I get the following error:
"DML currently not allowed"

I really need that the HTTP request be called when I click on the page to render the information from the api first, but I need to save the information in this custom object too if any kind of error happens.
Any ideas?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try a page action method?

Comment: Yes, but I catch the error in the HTTP request, and I need that HTTP request to run in the constructor. So if I use action method, that page is not rendered with the information from the api.

Comment: The page action method runs immediately after the constructor and http request can be done there

Comment: And how can I re-render the page with the information from the API after the action method run?
It's a simple page that only show the information from the api.

Comment: I apologize for the [page action method approach](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BO8lIAG) as it isn't 100% reliable - Bob Buzzard, the king of VF development suggests this approach: http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/08/dml-during-initialisation.html

Comment: It worked, very good approach without using action, thank you very much!

Comment: I don't know how to put your comment as best answer here in the comments, could you please create an answer down here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches to solve this

### Use a page action method to do the Http callout.

However, the [VF manual](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm?q=apex:page) recommends against doing this:

> The action method invoked when this page is requested by the server. Use expression language to reference an action method. For example, action="{!doAction}" references the doAction() method in the controller.
> If an action isn’t specified, the page loads as usual. If the action method returns null, the page simply refreshes.
>
> This method is called before the page is rendered, and allows you to optionally redirect the user to another page.
>
> Important: **Do not use this action for initialization or DML**.

Jill Wetzler, who was the original VF Developer Liaison also [recommends against doing this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F0000000957bIAA)

However, you will find references to this approach ([example](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BO8lIAG)) so YMMV

### Use JS to invoke a controller action method

This comes from Keir Bowden aka Bob Buzzard, author of the Visualforce Development Cookbook.  A `window.onload()` event handler invokes the controller's action method to do initialization.

Here, I'm quoting directly from [his blog post](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/08/dml-during-initialisation.html)

**VF Apex controller**

```
public class InsertObjectController 
{
 public Boolean initialised{get; set;}
 public Account acc {get; set;}
  
 public InsertObjectController()
 {
  initialised=false;
 }
  
 public void init()
 {
  if (!initialised)
  {
   acc=new Account();
   acc.Name='Blog Account';
   insert acc;
   initialised=true;
  }
 }
}
```

**VF page**

```
<apex:page controller="InsertObjectController">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:actionFunction name="doInit" action="{!init}" rerender="allPanel"/>
    <apex:outputPanel id="allPanel">
      <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(initialised)}">
        <p align="center" style='{font-family:"Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:20px;}'><apex:image value="/img/loading.gif"/>&nbsp;Please wait</p>
        <script>
           window.onload=function()
           {
             doInit();
           };
        </script>
      </apex:outputPanel>
      <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!initialised}">
        <apex:pageBlock title="Account Details">
          <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.id}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.name}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.type}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.industry}"/>
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```